# Korean Math Olympiad 2005 (trapezoid & tangent circles)

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a trapezoid $ABCD$ with $AD||BC$, $O_1$, $O_2$, $O_3$, $O_4$ denote the circles with diameters AB, BC, CD, DA, respectively. Show that there exists a circle with center inside the trapezoid which is tangent to all the four circles O1, O2, O3, O4 if and only if ABCD is a parallelogram.

[image]

I tried the following: let $AB = CD = 2r_1$, $BC = 2r_2$, $AD = 2r_3$, the circle tangent to $O_1, O_2, O_3, O_4$ has radius $r$, then we can solve:

$r=\frac{\sqrt{4r_1^2-(r_2-r_3)^2}-r_2-r_3}{2}$

If $O$ is externally tangent to $O_1$ and $O_3$, then $(r+r_1)^2=OP^2+O_1P^2$. If $O$ is internally tangent to $O_1$ and $O_3$, then $(r_1-r)^2=OP^2+O_1P^2$. Just need to prove that these equations do not hold as long as $r_2 \not= r_3$. But I ran into equations that seems unsolvable.
Is this the correct direction or there are better ways to prove?

Comment: We don't know that the trapezoid is necessarily isosceles, do we? $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{CD}$ *could* have differing lengths (until we determine that the tangent-circle condition makes them congruent and parallel).

Comment: Correct, for general trapezoid, it is even more difficult. I am just thinking if isosceles trapezoid does not work, then others won't work either.

Comment: This problem cannot be correct in the presented form. Consider an isosceles trapezoid such that the circles of diameters $AD$ and $BC$ are tangent. Then there exists a circle which is tangent to all of the $O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4$ and the quadrilateral is not a parallelogram.

Comment: Ok, with respect to my comment, if the circles of diameters $AD,BC$ are tangent then the circles $O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4$ all pass through the same tangency point, so there is no non-degenerate circle which can be tangent to all of them.